# Data entered via selenium webdriver sendKeys() not registering

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver, pageobjects

I am automating an insurance web application user journey. There are two fields which are based on list of matching selections from a hidden(initially) list. When the user starts entering text, it displays a matching list from where the user can select an option. 
I used sendKeys() method to enter the data and it seems accepting this as it matches with one of the valid options.

[image: Data Entry list]

[image]

But when I complete the form and click next, The form validation failed returning to the empty field.

[image]

Textbox html via inspect element

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control tt-input" value="" name="proposer_occupation_main_occupation_job_typeahead" data-    url="/quote/ajax/list/occupations" placeholder="enter job" data-field="occupation_job" data-field_name="proposer_occupation_main_occupation_job" data-    provides="ksp.field_type.typeahead" data-initialized="true" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" dir="ltr" style="position: relative; vertical-align:     top; background-color: transparent;">
```

Can anyone know how to handle this type of elements. What alternatives I can use instread of simply passing the value using sendKeys().

Used following xpath to idetify the element, it is working and inputting the tesxt as expected.

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@id='proposer_occupation_main_occupation_job']//input[contains(@placeholder,'enter job')]")
 WebElement InputJobTitle;
```

Only issue is when clicking submit, it came back with error on the field.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The source code interacting with WebElement InputJobTitle; is missing.

Comment: @Selaron updated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to click the value from dropdown using the respective selector of it.
The steps will be as follows,

- Send keys to the input
- Wait for dropdown appears
- Click the respective dropdown.

Comment: Should have been a comment rather.

Comment: Simple and powerful!! This worked for me. Added another click inside the element when the list appears to get the selection saved and values registered.